# How to load one jquery tab based on another tab in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

Rite now i am using two tabs one for countries and one for cities.IF i click first tab, countries will be loaded and second tab, cities will be loaded.Now what i want to achieve is when i click any of countries coming under the grid of first tab,then second tab is filled with corresponding countries cities only ,how will i do that,, country id and city c_id  has Primary key and foreign key relation ship

```
    <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab Header 1</a></li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tab Header 2", "_gridsecondtab")</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            @Html.Action("_gridfirsttab");
        </div>

firstgrid

<div id="gridfirstContent">
    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
            headerStyle: "header",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            selectedRowStyle: "select",
            columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("id", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.id.ToString())),
            grid.Column("countryname", "CountryName"),
            grid.Column("continent", "Continent", style: "description"),
            grid.Column("language", "Language")
     )) 
    @{
    firstmvc4.Models.Country conuntry = new firstmvc4.Models.Country();
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult _gridfirsttab()
    {
        return PartialView(db.Countries.ToList());

    }
      public ActionResult _gridsecondtab()
    {
        return PartialView(db.Citynews.ToList());

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this would normally be done is to use AJAX callbacks to populate the cities based on the user's country selection.  You mentioned jQuery in your title so that's what I assume you want.

Have your main page return a grid of countries, as you've done.  To populate the cities, normally one would return the data in JSON format and write some JavaScript to render the city list client-side.  Alternatively you could render HTML server-side and display it directly but that's less efficient.

Also read http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for how jQuery can be used to do an AJAX call from JavaScript.

Hope that helps.

Comment: small prototype is highly appreciated